# Basically: Create a 2x2 multidimensional array using C that adds, subtracts, multiple and divides

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I already finished creating the sum, difference, and product. What I am having trouble with is the quotient. because when I run it, It will just give me 0.0. I tried making the arrA and arrB a float which makes the quotient work but the others (sum, difference, and product) do not work. Please help me on how I could get the quotient to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int arrA[2][2];
    int arrB[2][2];
    float arrSum[2][2];
    float arrDiff[2][2];
    float arrProd[2][2];
    float arrQuo[2][2];
    int i,j;
    
    //1st Matrix
    printf("Enter Elements of 1st Matrix\n");
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) // size of rows
    {
        for(j=1; j<3; j++) // size of columns
        {
            printf("Enter a[%d][%d]: ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &arrA[i][j]); // to get value and save to array[][]
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Second Matrix
    printf("Enter Elements of 2nd Matrix\n");
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) // size of rows
    {
        for(j=1; j<3; j++) // size of columns
        {
            printf("Enter b[%d][%d]: ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &arrB[i][j]); // to get value and save to array[][]
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }
    
    
    // Sum of Matrix
    printf("Sum of Matrix: \n");
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) // size of rows
    {
        for(j=1; j<3; j++) // size of columns
        {
            arrSum[i][j] = arrA[i][j] + arrB[i][j];
            printf("%.1f ", arrSum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Difference of Matrix
    printf("Difference of Matrix: \n");
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) // size of rows
    {
        for(j=1; j<3; j++) // size of columns
        {
            arrDiff[i][j] = arrA[i][j] - arrB[i][j];
            printf("%.1f ", arrDiff[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Product of Matrix
    printf("Product of Matrix: \n");
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) // size of rows
    {
        for(j=1; j<3; j++) // size of columns
        {
            arrProd[i][j] = arrA[i][j] * arrB[i][j];
            printf("%.1f ", arrProd[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Quotient of Matrix
    printf("Quotient of Matrix: \n");
    for (i=1; i<3; i++) // size of rows
    {
        for(j=1; j<3; j++) // size of columns
        {
            arrQuo[i][j] = arrA[i][j] / arrB[i][j];
            printf("%.2f ", arrQuo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

here is the result:
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FupvE.png)

here is what it should look like:
[The supposed output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tog75.png)

Comment: `for (i=1; i<3; i++)` et al...Should be `for (i=0; i<2; i++)` Indexes are from `0` to `size - 1`. Same for the `j` loops.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I already tried that as well. nothing changed. I think its with the formula or how i could make "arrA" and "arrB" to a float without destroying the add, substract, and product of the matrix.

Comment: Since `arrA` and `arrB` are integer arrays and you don't want to change that, you need to cast when doing the division: `arrQuo[i][j] = (float)arrA[i][j] / arrB[i][j];`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp ohh!!! Just tried it! It works! I did not know that I could just cast a float without declaring it as a float on top, we were not taught with that and I tried looking for a formula that fits on google for like the last 2 hours. Dang. Thank you though!

Comment: Integer division does not produce a floating point result, no matter what type the quotient is assigned to.

Comment: Unless the question is about reading the input, there's no need for all this scanf code.  Just initialize the arrays!  This removes any ambiguity about what input you are providing, and greatly simplifies the code.

Comment: Note that this is not matrix multiplication. It's essentially just a parallelization of simple arithmetic. Not sure whether you meant matrices in mathematical sense or not, because that is also possible.

Comment: Use functions.  They are free.